# Сериализация синтаксис

Tags: сериализация

есть вот такой цикл

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach($param_name as $name) {
    //Параметры
    $i++;
    }
```

Как мне сериализовать данные в нем

```
                $new_data = [
                'art' => ['name' => 'art','value' => 'ART_ZN',],
                'qwe' => ['name' => 'qwe','value' => 'ART_ZN',],
                ];
```

serialize($new_data)

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, метку используемого языка

Comment: Синтаксиз сериализации зависит от 1)язык 2)библиотека.

Comment: Кажется, это php.

Comment: Да это PHP///////////

Comment: $multidimentional_array= array(
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   array(
   array("name", "Name_val"),
   array("City", "City_val"),
   array("Qwe", "Qwe_val") 
  ),
  }
  );
   
   echo serialize($multidimentional_array);

Comment: Неудачная попытка(((

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править", используйте ее для уточнения вопроса и меток, пожалуйста.